# IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping and TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.5, virtualization, virtualizingstackpanel

I have a problem with virtualization in TreeView when grouping objects. 
In .NET 4.5 was added helpful thing as VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping, and I am trying to use it in next code:

```
<UserControl><UserControl.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding SharedDevices}" x:Key="Cvs">
       <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            <componentModel:SortDescription PropertyName="Name" />
        </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Assignment" />
            <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Location" />
        </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
</UserControl.Resources>

<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Cvs}}"
                  VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
                 VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping="True"
                      VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard"
                     VirtualizingPanel.IsContainerVirtualizable="True"
                      VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit='Item'
                  VirtualizingPanel.CacheLengthUnit="Item"
                  >
            <TreeView.GroupStyle>                   
                <GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock
                    Text="{Binding  Path=Name}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                </GroupStyle>
            </TreeView.GroupStyle>


            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="data:Device"
                                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

When program launched, I expand parent object with included children and scroll TreeView. When parent object moved beyond the visible part, the program throws NullReferenceException, Source: PresentationFramework, StackTrace:

> in
>   System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.FindScrollOffset(Visual
>   v)
>
> in
>   System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MakeVisible(Visual
>   visual, Rect rectangle)    in
>   System.Windows.Controls.ScrollViewer.ExecuteNextCommand()    in
>   System.Windows.Controls.ScrollViewer.OnLayoutUpdated(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e)    in
>   System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.fireLayoutUpdateEvent()    in
>   System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayout()    in
>   System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayoutCallback(Object arg)
>   in System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.FireInvokeOnRenderCallbacks()
>   in System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandlerCore(Object
>   resizedCompositionTarget)    in
>   System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandler(Object
>   resizedCompositionTarget)    in
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate
>   callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)    in
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source,
>   Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)

This ecxeption throws before event VirtualizingStackPanel.CleanUpVirtualizedItem.

Is there any way to fix it? Thank You for answers!

UPD#1: tested on .Net 4.5.2 and .net 4.6.1 platforms

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14092691/1997232) (not sure if it's a duplicate).

Comment: tested on .Net 4.5.2 and .net 4.6.1. No changes

Answer (score 0):

I had the same bug on 4.6.1 and i've fixed it with upgrade the solution to 4.7.2 .NET version.